# String separater

Tags: python, string, list

I have a program that takes text input and stores a list of words that were input, but without duplicates. I need to store these in a file so I convert it into a string and join it with a comma between each word.

Now if there is a comma near a word then it would break. I therefore need a string to join the items of a list that is not part of any of the items.

For example if an item was "dog" the string og couldn't be used so the program would know this and add another letter on to make it a unique set of letters.

I then concatenate these strings to recreate the inputted text but it only works if the string I'm splitting them with is not part of the words.

I use @# now as it is unlikely that will be in the inputted text but I would like it to be perfect.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to be doing it like this? There are better ways of storing lists than deriving your own separator.

Comment: @Denziloe yes sadly, it is for a test testing specific skills. Sorry.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more straight to the point. How about using '\n'?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an existing serialization library that will convert your objects to string for you, without you having to invent an algorithm yourself. For instance, json:

```
>>> import json
>>> my_strings = ["foo", 'ba"r', "ba,z", "qu'x", "zo@#rt"]
>>> s = json.dumps(my_strings)
>>> s
'["foo", "ba\\"r", "ba,z", "qu\'x", "zo@#rt"]'
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> result = json.loads(s)
>>> result
['foo', 'ba"r', 'ba,z', "qu'x", 'zo@#rt']
>>> type(result)
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: thank you and this would work it's just I have to do it a specific way for a test. @Kevin

Comment: any ideas? It would really help. Also not a test more of an investigation to see how well we could do it in the real world so we are allowed to ask experts.@Kevin

Comment: Well, the simple solution would be to use "\n" as a separator, since those are impossible to enter using `input()`, so you know none of your words are going to contain it. If that is unsatisfying, I guess I'd just iterate through every possible separator, like `import string; import itertools; for i in itertools.count(1): for s in itertools.product(string.printable, repeat=i): ...` until I found a separator that doesn't exist in any word. (but this raises the question, when reading the file, how do you tell what separator you used when writing the file?)

Comment: thanks I will probably use \n and for knowing which seperater i used I could store it in a file. Not really going to be very compressed though hahaha. Thanks again!